# Deploying working react cosmosdb app from local to Azure

Tags: reactjs, api, azure, azure-cosmosdb

So I am new with working with react and have followed this tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-mongodb-react#project-setup) to assist me. All runs fine following these videos and all locally, but after doing a `npm run build` and then pushing to Azure via a local git repo, the UI runs as expected, but whenever the UI tries to hit the Express/Node backend, it gets an error that I am not understanding how to resolve. Looking at the build scripts that runs on both, I do not see where or if I need to change an environment variable as it is already hitting the correct port on Azure. What I get is the following:

[image]

What do I need to revise for this? Since webpack with the build script in `create-react-app` seems to do what it needs to, I am not quite sure where things are going wrong.

Comment: first error is 404 resource not found. Are you sure the connection string or the end points are right for that first particular call?

Comment: Thought so. That is why I am asking here as my connection string points to the resource already in Azure.